# Low pass filter output showing instability

Tags: matlab, filters, discrete-signals, lowpass-filter

I am fairly new to DSP, and I'm trying to implement the Pan Tompkins algorithm for QRS detection of ECG signals in MATLAB. The first stage of the algorithm consists of a second-order low-pass filter. The difference equation of the filter is

$$
y(n)=2y(n-1)-y(n-2)+x(n)-2x(n-6)+x(n-12)
$$

Here is the MATLAB code I have written.

```
load 108m.mat; sig_108 = val(1,:); clear val;
lowPassResult = lowPassFilter(sig_108);

figure;
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(lowPassResult);
title('Lowpass')
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(sig_108);
title('Original')

function y = lowPassFilter(x)
    %y(n)=2y(n-1)-y(n-2)+x(n)-2x(n-6)+x(n-12)
    y = zeros(1,21600);
    y(12) = 0;
    y(11) = 0;
    for n = 13:length(x)
        y(n) = 2*y(n-1)-y(n-2)+x(n)-2*x(n-6)+x(n-12);
    end
end
```

[image: Output of MATLAB code]

I am using ECG record 108 from the MIT-BIH arrhythmia database available at [PhysioBank ATM](https://archive.physionet.org/cgi-bin/atm/ATM). One problem I am having is that the output of the lowpass filter appears to grow without bound towards $+\infty$ as can be seen in the figure above. Where have I gone wrong in my code that could be causing this issue?

Comment: well the coefficients for the feedback paths correspond to two poles right on the unit circle at $z=1$.  to be stable they need to be inside the unit circle meaning $|z|<1$.

Comment: Yes, I actually did look into this by finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial in the time domain and found that the equation has a double root at $\lambda = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to explain Robert's answer below.

Apply Z-transform to both sides of the equation. You get the following:
\begin{align}
Y(z) [1 - 2z^{-1} + z^{-2}] = X(z)[1 -2z^{-6} + z^{-12}]
\end{align}

The transfer function is given as
\begin{align}
H(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{1 - 2z^{-1} + z^{}-2}{1 - 2z^{-6} + z^{-12}} = \frac{(1-z^{-6})^{2}}{(1-z^{-1})^{2}}
\end{align}

The denominator represents the poles of the filter $H(z)$. In this case, there exists two poles, both of which lie on the unit circle at $z=1$. For a filter to be stable, all the poles should lie inside the unit circle, i.e., the roots of the denominator polynomial of the transfer function $H(z)$ should lie inside the unit circle.

Perhaps, you can also try a different MATLAB implementation of the above filter:

```
a1 = [ 1 −2 1 ];
b1 = [ 1 0 0 0 0 0 −2 0 0 0 0 0 1 ];
lp_sig = filter( b1, a1, x );
```

Comment: I tried the code you provided and the correct output was generated. However, I can't use the built-in filter function, but now I know that my error lies in my code. I'm guessing it likely is due to the initial conditions of $y(n)$ that I have set.

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50588879/how-to-implement-iir-filter-in-c?

Comment: I did not, but I found that $x(n)$ is relaxed for $n<0$, so $x(n)=0$ for all $n<0$. Thus, I need to re-index the input by adding 12 zeros at the beginning of $x(n)$ to prevent any errors regarding negative indices.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I recently ran into this problem myself and spent a lot of time trying to figure it out. @brlauwer324 provides the answer in the comment: x(1:12) should be initialized to zero. Here's the MATLAB code:

```
function y = lowPassFilter(x)
    %y(n)=2y(n-1)-y(n-2)+x(n)-2x(n-6)+x(n-12)
    y = zeros(1,21600);
    y(12) = 0;
    y(11) = 0;
    for n = 1:12
        x(n) = 0.0;
    end
    
    for n = 13:length(x)
        y(n) = 2*y(n-1)-y(n-2)+x(n)-2*x(n-6)+x(n-12);
    end
end

load 108m.mat; sig_108 = val(1,:); clear val;
lowPassResult = lowPassFilter(sig_108);

figure;
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(lowPassResult);
title('Lowpass')
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(sig_108);
title('Original')
```

[image]